# Getting HTTP 404 Content Not Found error in Spring 5, WebTestClient

Tags: spring-boot, junit, spring-webflux

I'm writing a JUnit test using WebTestClient to test a service implementation class (not a controller class) but I'm keeping on getting following error :-

***  
     but was:<404>

> POST /authorizationserver/oauth/token
>   WebTestClient-Request-Id: [1]
>   Tenant-Id: [4370be48-6605-41da-89c5-dfc8945498ab]
>   Correlation-Id: [4370be48-6605-41da-89c5-dfc8945498ab]
>   User-Id: [6e9dd5ef-0dbd-4a76-83aa-75cb85732851]
>   Accept: [application/json;charset=UTF-8]

No content

< 404 Not Found
< Content-Type: [application/json;charset=UTF-8]

Content not available yet

```
at com.sap.chatbot.commerceconnector.CommerceAuthenticationProviderTest.testAccessTokenWithHeaders(CommerceAuthenticationProviderTest.java:94)
```

Caused by: java.lang.AssertionError: Status expected:<200> but was:<404>
    at com.sap.chatbot.commerceconnector.CommerceAuthenticationProviderTest.testAccessTokenWithHeaders(CommerceAuthenticationProviderTest.java:94)
]]>***

My classes are :-

CommerceAuthenticationProvider.java

```
 @Service("authenticationProvider")
public class CommerceAuthenticationProvider implements AuthenticationProvider {

  private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(CommerceAuthenticationProvider.class);

  @Override
  public AccessToken getUserAccessToken(Tuple2<String, WebClient> serviceConnectionDetails, MultiValueMap<String, String> queryParams) {
    return serviceConnectionDetails._2
        .post()
        .uri(builder -> builder
            .path(serviceConnectionDetails._1)
            .queryParams(queryParams)
            .build())
        .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
        .retrieve()
        .bodyToMono(AccessToken.class)
        .block();

  }

}
```

CommerceAuthenticationProviderTest.java :-

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT, classes = CommerceConnectorApplication.class)
//@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT, properties = {"spring.main.webApplicationType=reactive"})
//@SpringBootTest()
@ActiveProfiles("test")
@AutoConfigureWebTestClient
public class CommerceAuthenticationProviderTest {

  @Autowired
  private WebTestClient webTestClient;

  @MockBean
  private AuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider;

  public AccessToken getAccessToken() {

    return new AccessToken("c5680a38-8ce2-4a28-93e4-db00fac4a2f9", "bearer", "39767", "basic openid");

  }

  public MultiValueMap<String, String> queryParams() {

    MultiValueMap<String, String> queryParams = new LinkedMultiValueMap<>();

    queryParams.add(CommerceConnectorConstants.AUTHORIZATION_CLIENT_ID, "asm");

    queryParams.add(CommerceConnectorConstants.AUTHORIZATION_CLIENT_SECRET, "12341234");

    queryParams.add(CommerceConnectorConstants.AUTHORIZATION_GRANT_TYPE,
        CommerceConnectorConstants.REQUEST_HEADER_AUTHORIZATION_GRANT_TYPE);

    queryParams.add(CommerceConnectorConstants.AUTHORIZATION_USERNAME, "abc@test.com");

    return queryParams;

  }


 @Test
  public void testAccessToken() throws Exception {

    System.out.println("Test executed ->>>>>>>>>>>> "+webTestClient);
    when(authenticationProvider.getUserAccessToken(any(), any())).then((res) -> Mono.just(getAccessToken()));

    this.webTestClient.post().uri(builder -> builder.path("/authorizationserver/oauth/token")
        .queryParams(queryParams())
        .build())
            .header(CommerceConnectorConstants.TENANT_ID, "4370be48-6605-41da-89c5-dfc8945498ab")
            .header(CommerceConnectorConstants.CORRELATION_ID, "4370be48-6605-41da-89c5-dfc8945498ab")
            .header(CommerceConnectorConstants.TENANT_USER_ID, "6e9dd5ef-0dbd-4a76-83aa-75cb85732851")
            .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8)
            .exchange()
            .expectStatus()
            .isOk();
  }
}
```

POM.xml(code chunk):-

```
<parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.3.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-webflux</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
```

I tried all but not able to figure out the issue.
Please advise. Thanks

Comment: how is that authentication service is supposed to be communicating over HTTP? Are you using Spring Security? If so, could you share a bit more about your build file?

Comment: No, I'm not using any Spring Security. I get WebClient instance and make POST call to 3rd party (token service to get token)

Comment: Your application doesn’t seem to expose any web endpoint. I’m probably missing some piece of information here because I don’t know where your expectation for this endpoint to be present comes from

Comment: You need router- and handler functions or a controller to expose an endpoint.  https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/web-reactive.html#webflux-controller. Also, please get rid of the block() function in the service. Blocking calls break reactive (spring) applications since they are not prepared to handle blocking code.